# Latest value of a number in a month

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are files on disk, named liked this:

`<fille>-<year>_<month>_<release>*`
Example filenames:

```
/tmp/release-notes-v22_05_01.pdf
/tmp/release-notes-v22_05_02.pdf
/tmp/release-notes-v22_06_06.pdf
/tmp/release-config-v22_06_03.pdf
```

From this file, I have set a variable for the date and release number, example:

```
2022-05-01 00:00:00 01
2022-05-01 00:00:00 02
2022-06-01 00:00:00 06
2022-06-01 00:00:00 03
```

**Q:** How can I code python to print only the latest release of each month.
In this case, the output would be:

```
2022-05-01 00:00:00 02
2022-06-01 00:00:00 06
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [ask].

Comment: Yeah I'm stuck here.... I got no clue how to print the release numbers per month. That's an error in my head

Comment: Group the items into a dict where the keys are dates and the values are lists of items, then find the maximum of each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to easily group the results up. Since you didn't show your code to figure out the dates/versions from filenames, here's a version of that too.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

date_and_version_re = re.compile("v(\d+_\d+)_(\d+)")

filenames = [
    "release-notes-v22_05_01.pdf",
    "release-notes-v22_05_02.pdf",
    "release-notes-v22_06_06.pdf",
    "release-config-v22_06_03.pdf",
]

grouped = defaultdict(dict)  # {date: {version: filename}}

for filename in filenames:
    match = date_and_version_re.search(filename)
    date, version = match.groups()
    grouped[date][version] = filename

for date, versions in sorted(grouped.items()):
    highest_version = max(versions)
    print(date, highest_version, versions[highest_version])
```

This prints out

```
22_05 02 release-notes-v22_05_02.pdf
22_06 06 release-notes-v22_06_06.pdf
```

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow. Legendary.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the files has the same name format you can sort the list by the month and version and utilize the fact that dictionaries retain the last inserted value

```
files = sorted(os.listdir('tmp'), key=lambda x: x[-9:-5])
d = {f[-9:-5]: f for f in files}
print(list(d.values())) # ['release-notes-v22_05_02.pdf', 'release-notes-v22_06_06.pdf']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bit more functional solution you can use something like this:

```py
# Tools for working with iterators
import itertools
import re

filenames = [
    "release-notes-v22_05_01.pdf",
    "release-notes-v22_05_02.pdf",
    "release-notes-v22_06_06.pdf",
    "release-config-v22_06_03.pdf",
]

# Regex copied from AKX but using named groups for readability
date_and_version_re = re.compile("v(?P<year>\d+)_(?P<month>\d+)_(?P<release>\d+)")
# You can edit this function to find the max by any other category, for example remove month year to find the best for every year
group_key = lambda result: (result.group("year"), result.group("month"))

# list comprehensions should be read bottom to top
best_each_month = [
    # Format the result using format, using the names groups
    "20{year}-{month}-01 00:00:00 {release}".format(
        # Find the group with the highest release number. i[0] will be the key while i[1] is all the values
        **max(i[1], key=lambda k:k.group("release")).groupdict()
    # Group successive elements that share a key
    ) for i in itertools.groupby(
        # Sort the list so that successive elements are adjacent
        sorted((date_and_version_re.search(i) for i in filenames), key=group_key),
        # The group key is a generator that will decide if 2 elements should be grouped
        group_key
    )
]
print(best_each_month)
```